# Find unreachable/ deactivated mesos slaves agents

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I deployed dcos cluster on aws ec2 instances having a couple of mesos-slave agents. Few out of them were unexpectedly terminated. Mesos master marked them `"unreachable"`. I would like to change their status from "Unreachable" to `"Gone"`. To do that dcos provide following command:

```
dcos node decommission <mesos-id>
```

However, I am unable to find mesos-id of the unreachable mesos-agents. Neither `mesos-master` nor `dc/os` GUI/logs show any information for these nodes.

My question is how to get a list of all the unreachable (or deactivated) mesos-slave agents?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

To get an history of agents marked as unreachable use this command:

```
grep unreachable /var/log/mesos/*.INFO.*
```

or

```
gawk 'match($0, /.*Marking agent (.*) \(.*\) unreachable.*/, a) {print a[1]}' /var/log/mesos/*.INFO.*|sort|uniq
```

But if you only want to reset metrics reported in web ui you need to restart the mesos-master service (take a look at https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/monitoring/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with this I am able to fetch the unreachable agents.
However, when I restarted the decos-mesos-master service, I lost all the log files, Even I don't have any directory "var/log/dcos" or "var/log/mesos".
My basic objective was to remove the unreachable agents from master registry so master get to know that those agents are permanently gone. 
Any help in this regards?

Comment: Use this API: https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/operator-http-api/#mark_agent_gone

Comment: Or with Dcos CLI: https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/cli/command-reference/dcos-node/dcos-node-decommission/